# Get rid of "type qualifier" warnings on functions using the restrict keyword

Tags: c++, g++, suppress-warnings, restrict-qualifier, blitz++

I'm trying to clean up warnings that I'm getting when compiling Blitz++ of the form:

```
/opt/local/include/blitz/tinyvec2.h:261:35: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
/opt/local/include/blitz/tinyvec2.h:264:43: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers] 
/opt/local/include/blitz/tinyvec2.h:267:40: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
<<etc.>>
```

From these kinds of member functions (of the `TinyVector` class)

```
T_numtype * restrict data()    // line 261                      
    { return data_; }          // data is a member that is an array of data values

const T_numtype * restrict data() const       // line 264       
    { return data_; }
```

As far as I can tell I am getting the warnings due to the `restrict` keyword.  Note: there are macros that should replace the `restrict` with `__restrict__` (which g++ understands).

I can get rid of the warnings by deleting the keywords; however, since this is supposed to be a high-performance numerical library, I don't want to lose any compiler optimizations that the `restrict` keywords are allowing.

What can I do to suppress these warnings without just dropping the `restrict`'s altogether, and while keeping `-Wall` on?

Comment: If it's an internal thing like that and this suggestion won't break anything else by ignoring other warnings, put Blitz in the include directories via `-isystem path/to/Blitz`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> <sup>**README**</sup>
>
> <sup>`__restrict__` has no usage on return-types, which is exactly why `gcc` is giving you the diagnostic. The keyword is used to signal that two pointers passed to a function doesn't point to the same object, ie. that they are unique; changing one will not affect the other. This can greatly improve optimizations, but it's worth noting that it won't affect the returned value of a function.</sup>
>
> <sup>There's no reason for you to apply `__restrict__` on the return type.</sup>

<sup>The above *README* is written by me, I used *quotations*  to draw some extra attention to it since the information contained is important to the matter at hand..</sup>

---

**Ignore warning using gcc specific pragma**

You could ask `gcc` to disregard diagnostics matching `-Wignored-qualifiers` by using [*diagnostic pragmas*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html).

- [Diagnostic Pragmas - Using the GNU Compiler Collection (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html)

---

**Ignore it everywhere**

This will ignore every warning that `-Wignored-qualifiers` would enable;

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wignored-qualifiers"
```

---

**Ignore it for a seleted area**

This will ignore `-Wignored-qualifiers` related warnings for the code replaced by `...`

```
... // warnings enabled

#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wignored-qualifiers"

... // warning disabled here

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop

... // warnings enabled again
```

---

<sup>**Note**: `-Wignored-qualifiers` is enabled through `-Wextra`, not `-Wall`.</sup>

Comment: Is the "README" section from g++ documentation, or a standard or something?

Comment: @Dave no, it's written by me (just wanted to draw some extra attention do it, that's why I used `>` (quotations)), I'll edit this into the post.

Comment: Mostly I was waiting to see if anyone else chimed in; I'm suspicious of the fact that restrict on return values has no effect, but is valid syntax.