# In which cases will the restrict qualifier applied to a return value have an effect?

Tags: c++, restrict-qualifier

If I have a member function declared like so:

```
double* restrict data(){
    return m_data; // array member variable
}
```

can the restrict keyword do anything?

[Apparently, with g++ (x86 architecture) it cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961279/get-rid-of-type-qualifier-warnings-on-functions-using-the-restrict-keyword), but are there other compilers/architectures where this type of construction makes sense, and would allow for optimized machine code generation?

I'm asking because the Blitz library (Blitz++) has a whole slew of functions declared in this manner, and it doesn't make sense that someone would go in and add the restrict keyword unless it actually does something.  So before I go in and remove the `restrict`'s (to get rid of compiler warnings) I'd like to know how I'm abusing the code.

Comment: is there anything in the answers provided that is not clear enough?

Comment: I'm looking for a use-case where restrict applied to a return value has an effect.

Comment: there's no such case in any common implementation, and the rationale behind `restrict` in the C standard doesn't include any usage in *return-statements*.

Comment: This is further supported by the contents of this mail-thread, from within the development of the Blitz++ Library: http://sourceforge.net/p/blitz/mailman/message/21664429/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WHAT `restrict` ARE WE TALKING ABOUT?**

`restrict` is, as it currently stands, non-standard.. which means that it's a compiler extension; it's non-portable in the sense that the C++ Standard doesn't mandate its existance, nor is there any formal text in it that tells us what it is supposed to do.

`restrict` is currently compiler specific in C++, and one has to resort to the compiler documentation of their choice to see exactly what it is doing.

---

**SOME THOUGHTS**

There are many papers about the usage of `restrict`, among them:

- [Restricted Pointers - Using the GNU Compiler Collection](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html)
- [restrict - wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict)
- [Demystifying The Restrict Keyword - CellPerformance](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/05/demystifying-the-restrict-keyword.html)

It's hinted at several places that the purpose of `restrict` is to qualify pointers so that the compiler knows that two pointers in the same scope doesn't refer to the same memory location.

With this in mind we can easily see that the return-type has no potential *collision* with other pointers, so using it in such context will generally not gain any optimization opportunities. However; one **must** refer to the documented behaviour of the used implementation to know for sure.. as stated: `restrict` is not standard, [yet](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3635.pdf).

---

I also found the following thread where the developers of *Blitz++* discusses the removal of `strict` applied to the return-type of a function, since it doesn't do anything:

- [**Re: [Blitz-devel] type qualifiers ignored on function return type**](http://sourceforge.net/p/blitz/mailman/message/21664429/)

---

**A LITTLE NOTE**

As a further note, here's what the [*LLVM Documentation*](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#noalias) says about `noalias` vs `restrict`:

> For function return values, C99’s restrict is not meaningful, while LLVM’s noalias is.

Comment: It's not merely not mandated in C++; `restrict` is a valid identifier so it can't be a keyword in a conforming compiler.

Comment: @AlanStokes I will update the post, you are correct that a confirming c++ compiler cannot have `restrict` as a keyword. **edit**: *fixed*.

Answer (score 0):

Generaly restrict qualifier can only help to better optimize code. By removing 'restrict' you don't break anything, but when you add it without care you can get some errors. A great example is the difference between memcpy and memmove. You can always use slower memmove, but you can use faster memcpy only if you know that src and dst aren't overlaping.

Comment: Thanks, but that (and similar) examples involve `restrict` applied to function arguments (and similar) not function _return values_.